# convert firebase 1 to firebase 2 code

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm following a tutorial online.  This tutorial covers firebase 1, however I'm currently using firebase 2

In one of the code samples he has written a reference like so

```
private var postRef: firebase
```

however when I do this within firebase 2 I get the error "Use of undeclared type 'firebase'

Now my issues is I'm trying to find the comparison between firebase 1 and 2 so I can go ahead an implement the correct code, however I've been unsuccessful in finding such information.

Can someone shed some light in regards to what the correct syntax is for firebase 2 ?

The value he assigns to this variable is a value from one of the tables, in this case its from a post table, which consists of Desc, image, Id

Comment: I think it should be `FIRDatabaseReference` instead `firebase`

Comment: That's correct, thanks.

Comment: mention not ... :)

Comment: Please be accurate when using version number or provide references (or provide a link to the tutorial you're following). To give you some idea: it is very likely that you're trying to upgrade from version 2.x of the Firebase SDK to version 3.x here. But without references we can't be sure, so I can't even fix it in your question for you. Also note that we have an upgrade guide that covers such steps: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios#get_a_database_reference_numbered

Answer (score 1):

just change :-

```
 private var postRef: firebase
```

to

```
 private var postRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
```

Which you can later initialise in any scope...like:-

```
 override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
          postRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

           }
```

Comment: Accept and +1 this answer if it solved your issue :) Happy Coding